# how to show close button on right top side instead of left

Tags: html, css

[image]I am using light box for image but the close array display at the left top but i want it to the right I am new to CSS.

My HTML code is given for light box on linkbutton one

```
           <div class="linkbutton"> 

           <a href="image/popup_page_1.png" rel="lightbox"><img src="image/smallicon_2.png"  alt="" /></a>
            </div>


        </div>
```

```
       <div id="page_two" class="panel">
            <div class="main_heading_two">Strategy</div>
            <div class="menu">
                <ul>
                    <li class="stix"></li>
                    <li><a href="#page_one"><img src="image/overview.gif" /></a></li>
                    <li class="stix"></li>
                    <li><a href="#page_two"><img src="image/strategy_active.png"/></a></li>
                    <li class="stix"></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="image/draxxin.gif"/></a></li> 
                    <li class="stix"></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="image/excede.gif"/></a></li>
                    <li class="stix"></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="image/results.gif"/></a></li>
                    <li class="stix"></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="image/reference.gif"/></a></li> 
                    <li class="stix"></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="rightclass_one"><img src="image/whiteslide.png"/></div>  
            <div class="pagetwo_text"><p>Get up to 21 days of BRD therapy strategy using longer-duration antimicrobials DRAXXIN ® (tulathromycin) Injectable Solution and EXCEDE ® (ceftiofur crystalline free acid) Sterile Suspension.
                </p></div>
            <div class="pagetwo_list_text">Advantages for Producers:
                <ul><li>Fewer treatments</li>
                    <li>Less stress on cattle</li>
                    <li>Fewer mortalities</li>
                    <li>Cattle can recover in their own pen
                    </li>
                    <li>Lower treatment costs and higher profits
                    </li></ul></div>
            <div class="pagetwo_list_text2">Extended duration strategy
            </div>
            <div>
                <ul>
                    <li class="midmenu_1"><a href="#page_one"><img src="image/backward.png"/></a></li>
                    <li class="midmenu_2"><a href="#page_two"><img src="image/forward.png"/></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="right_text"><p>Either way you use them, it takes both DRAXXIN and EXCEDE for control and treatment of BRD in high-risk cattle to give you the longest duration of BRD therapy
                </p></div>
            <div class="image_21"><img src="image/pagetwo_graph_two_4.png"/></div>
            <div class="ratemeter"><img src="image/pagetwo_graph_one.png"/></div>
            <div id="one"   class="image_one" ><img src="image/optiononetwo.png"/></div>
            <div id="two"  class="image_two"><img src="image/optiononeone.png"/></div>
            <div id="three" class="image_one_one" ><img src="image/pagetwo_graph_two_11.png" /></div>
            <div id="four" class="image_two_two" ><img src="image/pagetwo_graph_two_22.png"
                /></div>



            <div class="option_image"><img src="image/option_1.png"  onclick="showHideDiv()"/></div>



            <div class="option_image_label">Option 1</div>
            <div class="option_image_one"><img src="image/option_1.png" onclick="showHideView()"/></div>
            <div class="option_image_label_one">Option 2</div>
            <div class="fourteen_day"><img src="image/button_14days.PNG"/></div>
            <div class="heading_one">Post Metaphylaxis Interval (PMI)</div>


            <div class="linkbutton_one">

            <a href="image/popup_1_page_2.png" rel="lightbox"><img src="image/smallicon_1.png"  alt="" /></a>
            </div>


            <div class="seven_day"><img src="image/button_7days.PNG"/></div>
            <div class="heading_two">Post Treatment Interval (PTI)</div>
            <div class="linkbutton_two">
            <a href="image/popup_2_page_2.png" rel="lightbox"><img src="image/smallicon_1.png"  alt="" /></a>
           </div>


        </div><!-- End of page two-->
```

Belos is my css  which used for light box

```
.lb-data .lb-close {
    width:35px;
    position: absolute;
    float: right;
    padding-bottom: 0.7em;
    outline: none;
    top:-35px;
}
```

[image]
    Image shows cross sign on right side but far away from image

Answer (score 1):

apply:

```
 right:0px;
```

float won't work in conjunction with absolute positioning.

Answer (score 1):

Write like this:

```
 .lb-data .lb-close {
 width:35px;
 position: absolute;
 padding-bottom: 0.7em;
 outline: none;
 top:-35px;
right:0;
```

}

& there is no need to define **float** when you use **position:absolute** because **float** is not work with **position:absolute**

Comment: see the second image where i use this code which is smaller image it displays like this

Comment: may be close button parent DIV is not shrink with image

Comment: may be you have to define position:relative to it's parent

Comment: can you create a http://jsfiddle.net/ so it's understand your problem better & here is article what i mean by position:relative to it's parent http://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/

Comment: yes right @sandeep parent should be relative... than we can adjust the things easily in child container through absolute positioning.....

Answer (score 0):

It's not easy to answer without seeing some other html code, anyway float and `position: absolute` don't work together. I suggest you to remove the floating and add `right: 0;` to your css definition. You should also be sure that the parent of `.lb-close` has set `position: relative`;

Answer (score 0):

```
.lb-data .lb-close 
{
 width:35px;
 position: absolute;
 /*float: right;*/ <-- delete this
 padding-bottom: 0.7em;
 outline: none;
 top:-35px;
 right: 0; <-- new line to add
}
```

Comment: its ok but what to do when image is small

Comment: what is the problem when image is too small? Could you show us your html code as well?

Comment: actually, the html code after lightbox javascript execution would be more useful.. the solution is to give position: relative; to the parent of close button.

Comment: i did not understand can you explain me

Comment: I need to see the actual code AFTER js execution. Lightbox does modify your code, e.g. adding classes to some divs. In alternative, can you upload somewhere that html and link it to us?

Answer (score 0):

One important thing **float** doesn't work with **absolute-position** so you don't need to define float over here u just need to add **right:0;** i hope this will work smoothly....

```
  .lb-data .lb-close {
        width:35px;
        position: absolute;
        padding-bottom: 0.7em;
        outline: none;
        top:-35px;
        right:0;
    }
```

**UPDATED ANSWER**
 see here the demo is working fine:- 
http://jsbin.com/ilixux/5/edit

I have made this through **position:relative;** to its parent and **position:absolute;** to its child and now its working fine as you can see....

Comment: i think there is some positioning problem that's why you are not getting your desired results you just define position:relative; to your .lb-data parent class not child class or can see my updated answer how i have implemented the css.....

Comment: Can you edit my css file i edit in it but it seems not working you have written your owns css in online demo test mine

Comment: lbl.data is coming from jquerrry that's why i think that's not working

Comment: ya it can be possible because its coming dynamically i think this is the problem because its working fine on static level demo's but when you are creating with dynamical files than u r facing problems....

Answer (score -1):

add **left:** to your css code and place it where you exactly desire it.

eg:

```
left: 100px;
```

Comment: yes i did it but when i have some small image then what to do

Comment: Since you have used position: absolute; in css, you should make use of top,left,right, bottom in your css to place block exactly where you want. Seems right: 0px; did the trick for you.